# View GPU processor activity in real time?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, intel-graphics, gpu, top

I wanted to know if there is such a terminal command or application that allows one to view the progress of the processes running on the GPU in real time. Basically, something like 'top' for the GPU.

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 on a Toshiba Satellite with an Intel 4000 graphic card and I look forward to parallelize some computations with pyOpenCL. So I want to be able to monitor the processes of a GPU at real time. Is this GPU-brand-dependent? Do only GPU vendors provide such a utility or is there a general command one can easily execute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is hardware-specific.
For Intel graphics you can use `sudo intel_gpu_top`, which should do exactly what you want.
If you don't have it (which is very unlikely), just install `intel-gpu-tools`.